# Find the ratio of the sides

Tags: geometry

> The point $D$ is on the median $CM$ of the triangle $ABC$, such that $CD:DM = 1:3.$ If the point $E$ is the intersection of the straight line $AD$ and the side $BC$, what is $ CE:CB$ ?

So for simplicity, let $CD = 1$ and $DM =3$ thus $CM = 4$. Also $AM = MB$.

I am not the best at Geometry so I am not getting this problem (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $F=BD\cap AC$. By [Van Obel's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/VanObel.shtml):
$$ \frac{CF}{FA}+\frac{CE}{EB}=\frac{CD}{DM}=\frac{1}{3} \tag{1}$$
and by [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva's_theorem):
$$ \frac{CE}{EB}\cdot \frac{AF}{FC} = 1 \tag{2}$$
hence $\frac{CF}{FA}=\frac{CE}{EB}=\frac{1}{6}$ and:
$$ \frac{CE}{CB}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{7}}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

By [Menelaus' theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MenelausTheorem.html), we have
$$\frac{BA}{AM}\cdot\frac{MD}{DC}\cdot\frac{CE}{EB}=1.$$
It follows from this that $CE:EB=1:6.$

Hence, 
$$CE:CB=\color{red}{1:7}.$$